# how to go back page with initial navigation bar? xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

(with `navigationController`) `UITableViewController`(main page) >>(push)>>> `UIViewController` (detail page) >>(push)>>> `UIViewController` (editing page)

I can enter "main page", then enter "detail page", then enter "editing page", and all use "push" segue.

When I done editing in the editing page, I will press the save button.

If I make a "Modal" Segue for "save" button goes from [editing page] back to [detail page], there is no navigation bar on the page. 
If I make a "push" segue for "save" button goes from [editing page] back to [detail page], the "back" button on the navigation bar in [detail page] leads back to the [editing page], instead of [main page].

How can i go back to the [detail page] when done editing, and the "back" in [detail page] could leads to [main page].

Hope I have explained the problem clearly, and thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your editingView Controller look like this then you do not have to worry about back button because it will take you too detailView controller and on the save button you can pop your view controller to rootViewController which is your mainView like ...

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. When done editing, and pressed "save". I want to go back to detailViewController, not mainView.

Comment: then change the line with [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: awesome. It is working. hahahaha Also, one more quick question: how can i refresh the page when I go back to detailViewController? Because I have edited the details already.

Comment: if you want to reload the data in UITableView then you have to fetch the data and call [self.tableView reloadData]; method in your viewDidAppear: method, or if you know the delegation then that's more appropriate way

Answer (score 0):

Try this for back to Root view controller ...

```
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

:)

Comment: Thank you for answering. If I give this to "save" button, I will back to "main page" which is the rootViewController from the [editing page]. But I want goes to the "detail page".

Comment: awesome.  It is working. hahahaha   Also, another quick question: how can i refresh the page when I go back to detailViewController? Because I have edited the details already.

Comment: in viewWillAppear . you need to update all values... only viewWillappear will call there on popToView...